# Getting values from inside web page links

Tags: c, perl, copy, web

I have a static page, which contains multiple links to text files on the server. (around 100 links which all open a text file contents on the web browser itself).

The text files have text and numbers, where I need to get a specific number with a percentage (i.e., 52.56%), and store it to another text/csv file with the name of the link.

Links are basically in a single line format:

```
VAA007
VAB038
VAC041
VAD050
VAE031
VEA032
VEB053
VEC044
VEF015
```

The text files has the following values, along with lots of other text and numbers:

```
# Result Summary:
# Overall Run:191,Not Run:161,Covered:54.26%
```

The link address/URL is in the following format:

```
https://myWeb.local/~gags/cgi-bin/latestRun.pl
https://myWeb.local/~gags/cgi-bin/showReport.pl?fn=/OUT/VAA007.txt       
https://myWeb.local/~gags/cgi-bin/showReport.pl?fn=/OUT/VAD050.txt
```

Is there some easy way to work out the above and get the results into a text file or CSV file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
!/bin/sh
URL=https://myWeb.local/~gags/cgi-bin/showReport.pl?fn=/OUT/
for file in `cat links.txt`
do
  curl -s "$URL$file.txt" | awk -F':' '/^# Overall/ {print $NF}' > "$file.txt"
done
```

Assuming the links are stored in the file `links.txt`. If you need to fetch them first, you could add `curl -s https://someurl > links.txt` to the top of the script.

You don't specify if you have to log on to the server, and if so what kind of log on scheme is used. If that's a requirement, that's easily handled with `curl`.

Comment: The pages are HTTPS, and hence are giving Unknown/unsupported protocol. :-(

Comment: @gagneet: You haven't specified whether you need to log on, but if you don't you can just add the `-k`/`--insecure`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can run a .NET program for this, I recommend:

1. Get the [HtmlAgility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)
2. Use the HtmlAgility pack to [parse out all anchor tags](http://runtingsproper.blogspot.com/2009/11/easily-extracting-links-from-snippet-of.html)
3. For each anchor tag, extract the `href` value and use it to hit your page like this:

   ```
   WebClient wc = new WebClient();
   //Authenticate:
   wc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("[USER]", "[PASSWORD]", "[DOMAIN]");
   var url = "[THE URL FORM THE ANCHOR]";

   var result = wc.DownloadString(url);
   var resultArray = result.Split(',');

   var percent = resultArray[2].Split(':');

   return percent;
   ```

Comment: Thanks Matthew, I cannot edit the page, as it is generated on the server, and I currently do not have write access on the system. If you can provide the C# or .NET code, that would be great... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Untested, of course, because you do not provide sufficient input data.

```
use strictures;
use Text::CSV qw();
use WWW::Mechanize qw();
use autodie qw(:all);

my $static_page = 'http://…';
# or perhaps 'file://…' if reading from the local file system
my $url_pattern =
    qr'https://myWeb[.]local/~gags/cgi-bin/showReport[.]pl[?]fn=/OUT/(V.....)[.]txt';

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 2 })
    or die 'Cannot use CSV: ' . Text::CSV->error_diag;
open my $out, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', 'percentages.csv';
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;

$mech->get($static_page);

for my $link ($mech->find_all_links(url_regex => $url_pattern)) {
    my $text_file_url = $link->url_abs;
    my ($v_id) = $text_file_url =~ /$url_pattern/;
    $mech->get($text_file_url);
    my $content = $mech->content;
    my ($percentage) = $content =~ /Covered:(.*)%/;
    $csv->print($out, [$v_id, $percentage]);
}

close $out;
```

Comment: The pages are HTTPS, and hence are giving Unknown/unsupported protocol. :-(

Answer (score -1):

You may try SGMLParser & urllib if you know some python.